# Function before design, or a little of both?

Tags: css, database, design

When creating data-driven web pages, do you generally work on:

A) functionality first 
B) presentation first?
C) both at the same time

I'm learning how to build css sites and wasn't sure of the best approach.  There will be ajax calls and updates but that is pretty easy to implement.

Thanks for your time and feedback.

Comment: Good question for programmers.SE?

Comment: Should be moved to programmers

Answer (score 1):

Usually my workflow is like this:

1st. Front end design (HTML, CSS, Graphics, Fireworks etc)

2nd. Back end functionality (PHP, MySQL )

3rd. JavaScript & AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I personally find that figuring out what layout/presentation as well as what workflow I want helps clarify how I would like to write my code. I start with the "front-end" pages (without javascript), and then go about implementing functions one by one. This also helps test your functions as you write them which always helps.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to look at what the site does and identify the entities. Having screenshots or some use cases are helpful because then I will know how the site will be used.

Once that is done, I break it down into parts (product, user, CMS). Then I break those parts down into models and start working on the entities on database level. And then I build up from there. I use prototyping a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have an agreed 'spec' from the client I tend to work on both at the same time. Once you have the spec things are much easier. Without the spec working from the design can through up issues earlier.